# How to add YouTube VrView button in my App and only display 360 degree video in app that are com from playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

**I want to ask two things regarding youtube integration in my app:**

> 1. add youtube vrview button in my app.Also tried too many examples but can not
>       view youtube vrview button in app.
> 2. Want to display only 360 degree videos in my app. Also made custom YouTube 
>       player but not getting that vrview button. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[VR view](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview) allows you to embed 360 degrees VR media into site on desktop and mobile and native apps on Android and iOS. VR view supports mono and stereo 360 images and videos. Images and video need to be stored in the equirectangular-panoramic (equirect-pano) format, which is a common format supported by many capture solutions.

To use the VR View class, you need to include the Google-provided VR View script within your HTML.

```
<script src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>
```

Next, add a placeholder where you want the iframe that will contain the photosphere content to go.

```
<div id="vrview"></div>
```

When the VR View is loaded, this placeholder line will be replaced by an iframe with class=’vrview'.

When the web page loads, you want to register that it has loaded and then call a function that creates a new VR View instance:

```
window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
function onVrViewLoad() {
  var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
    video: 'link/to/video.mp4',
    is_stereo: true
  });
}
```

Note that by itself, this is equivalent to simply declaring an iframe with the same parameters:

```
<iframe src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/embed?video=link/to/video.mp4&is_stereo=true">
</iframe>
```

However, using the VR View JavaScript API offers additional features not available when explicitly declaring an iframe.